# How to create a wifi hotspot and use it on WP7.5?

Tags: wireless

I have been trying for many days to create a wifi hotspot with my laptop running ubuntu 12.04 and connect it to my windows phone7.5 based HTC Mozart. I have gone through many articles related to this, but none of them help.

I create a wifi hotspot as suggested by some experts, but it isn't detected either by my phone or on other laptops.
My laptop is Sony Vaio VPCEB14EN with these [specifications](http://www.sony-asia.com/product/vpceb14en) .

Comment: You left out the single most important part of relevant data...your wireless chipset.

Comment: In the future please take the time to phrase your questions in a better manner.

Comment: @nikhil yea sure i will... but kindly answer me my query..!!

Comment: @aking1012 my wireless chipset is: Intel® HM55 Express Chipset with Wireless LAN Type  Integrated Wireless LAN IEEE 802.11b/g/n

Comment: Edit your question with new information, don't just reply in the comments, it creates confusion...

Answer (score 3):

You can create a wifi-hotspot like following:

### Gnome-Shell:

- Click on the little network icon, at the top panel.
  [image]
- Select **"Network Settings"**
- Select **"Wireless"** in the left pane.
  [image]
- Click on the On/Off toogle on the right pane.
  [image]
- Click on **"Use as hotspot"**, You don't need to specify name
  [image]

That's it. A wireless wifi-hotspot is created with autocreated name and security key. The network name and security key is displayed immediately.
[image]

See the screenshots below.

### Unity:

- Click on the network activity icon,  a menu will appear like the one below.
  [image]
- Click on **"Create new wireless network..."**, a window will appear like this[image]
- Type in your network name and security key.
  [image]
- Click on create button.

A network will be created with the name typed.

You can now see in your HTC phone this newly created network. There must be an option for "checking available network" or "refresh network".

Answer (score 0):

http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1758347.html

> Understand that its not the "gb" (which I'm assuming means "gigabytes"
>   as in you have enough storage space on your hard drive), it's the
>   amount of work that you'll need to do not only for your laptop that
>   will become the Wifi connection, but on the mobile devices, too. That
>   said, let's start (relatively) easy. We'll create a connection between
>   your laptop and another device over the wireless interface.  First, we
>   need to find out what your wired connection settings are. To get this
>   information, right-click on the network manager icon and select
>   "Connection information". (NOTE: That's the connection that appears in
>   the upper, righthand corner of your screen and is typically next to
>   the icon for your sound and for your Evolution e-mail.) This will tell
>   you your IP address and, more importantly, the "Route" and "Primary
>   DNS". Note those two things (route and primary DNS).  We're going to
>   start by creating an ad-hoc network connection on your laptop.
>   Right-click on the network manager icon and select "Edit connections".
>   In the window that opens, select the "Wireless" tab and click on the
>   "Add" button. Here are the values to enter in the various windows:
>
> - Connection Name: Whatever you want to call it, such as "My Hotspot".
> - SSID: This will be the "name" of your hotspot that others might see to connect to it.
> - Mode: Select "Adhoc"
> - Band: I suggest selecting "B/G".
> - Channel: You can either leave this as is, or choose a specific number. If you're in the US, it will have to be a number between 1 -
>
>   1. I've found that 11 tends to work best because most people choose either the default (which is 6 normally) or 
>        1.
> - BSSID: Leave blank.
> - Device MAC Address: Leave blank.
> - Cloned MAC Address: Leave blank.
> - MTU: Leave as "automatic".
>
> Don't hit "Apply" yet. Select the "Wireless Security" tab and make
>   sure it says, "None".
>
> Now select the "IPV4 Settings" tab.
>
> - Method: Choose "Manual".
> - Next to "Addresses" click "Add".
> - Under the "Address" column, enter "192.168.100.1", with a netmask of "255.255.255.0".
>
> Under "Gateway", enter the IP address you got from "Route" in your
>   wired connection. For example, here at my house, my IP addresses are
>   192.168.1.x. The router (a Fios-provided router) is at 192.168.1.1. That's the IP address I would put in under "Gateway". For you, I'm
>   assuming you have a Motorola cable modem. Put in the IP address of
>   that (which should be the same as what you got from "Route" for your
>   wired connection.) Under DNS servers, put the IP address you got for
>   "Primary DNS" of your wired connection. For the secondary DNS, I
>   always put "8.8.4.4", which is a Google public DNS server.
>   - Leave the box checked that says, "Require IPv4 for this connection to complete".
>
> Now click "Apply".
>
> Now,*LEFT*-click on your network manager icon and select "Connect to
>   Hidden Wireless Network". Next to where it says "Connection", click on
>   the drop-down menu and you should see the name of the connection you
>   just created. Select it and then click on "Connect".
>
> At this point, your laptop can be become part of an ad hoc network.
>   You should see the network manager begin flickering, then it should
>   announce "My HotSpot connection established" (or whatever you named
>   your wireless connection).
>
> Leave it up for a minute or two, then see if any of your other
>   wireless devices can "see" it when looking for available wireless
>   connections.

Comment: @Alvar I have created the wireless as suggested by you.But it is not visible in my phone.Can u suggest me any other idea.

Comment: @VPCEB14EN I haven't done anything. What are you refereeing to? I just edited the answer.

Comment: Dave: @VPCEB14EN can't get your answer to work, can you help him further?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link for those who created a network but their phone doesn't recognizes it:
[Click here and get it working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/180733/tutorial-how-to-setup-wi-fi-hotspot-access-point-mode)

Comment: your link may provide the answer but please place part of your answer here .