# How to share wired Internet through ad-hoc Wi-Fi connection via a laptop?

Tags: wireless, internet

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to share a wired internet connection via Wifi?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60980/how-to-share-a-wired-internet-connection-via-wifi)

Is there a way I can share my wired Internet connection through my ad-hoc Wi-Fi connection, like I could do in Windows with [Connectify](http://www.connectify.me)?

I am using Ubuntu Studio 12.04.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways...

1. [Network Manger Method](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147445/how-to-create-a-wifi-hotspot-and-use-it-on-wp7-5) (See the second answer)
2. [IP Table Method](https://askubuntu.com/questions/104264/mobile-broadband-sharing-over-adhoc-wireless) (See the first answer)
3. [FireStarter Method](http://www.freesoftwaremagazine.com/articles/howto_share_mobile_broadband_ubuntu_using_only_gui) (Using a firewall to redirect Internet)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. WIFI hotspot enables your device to acts like an access point where other device with wirless connectivity can join the particular network. Here's the step by step tutorial:
http://freshtutorial.com/create-your-own-wifi-hotspot-in-ubuntu-11-10/

Comment: That site seems to have been hacked,